# How to generate a sitemap.xml using laravel-sitemap without images url?

Tags: php, laravel, xml-sitemap

I am using [spatie](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sitemap) to generate sitemap.xml. It is working properly as it is expected. But as per some requirement I would like to not include any image url in sitemap.xml.

This is my code -

```
public function sitemap(){
        
        $link   =   Website::where('adminId', Auth::user()->id)->value('link');

        $path = public_path('uploads/'.Auth::user()->id.'/sitemap.xml');

        if (file_exists($path)) {
            File::delete($path);
            fopen($path, 'w');
        } else {
            fopen($path, 'w');
        }

        SitemapGenerator::create($link)->writeToFile($path);

        return response()->json('success');
    }
```

Currently my `sitemap.xml` something looks like this with image links -

```
<url>
<loc>http://www.example.com/uploads/3/page/anahera/1591769129-4412.jpeg</loc>
<lastmod>2020-06-23T11:22:59+12:00</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>0.8</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>http://www.example.com/uploads/3/page/anahera/1591769136-7646.jpeg</loc>
<lastmod>2020-06-23T11:22:59+12:00</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>0.8</priority>
</url>
```

This there any way to remove those image links from sitemap.xml?

Appreciate for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow this part of document - [spatie](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sitemap#leaving-out-some-links). This is not specifically omit images but if there is any specific format in your url for images link - `http://www.example.com/uploads` then try to get `segment(1)` and compare so this part of documentation will work.

In your case as an example -

```
public function sitemap(){
        
        $link   =   Website::where('adminId', Auth::user()->id)->value('link');

        $path = public_path('uploads/'.Auth::user()->id.'/sitemap.xml');

        if (file_exists($path)) {
            File::delete($path);
            fopen($path, 'w');
        } else {
            fopen($path, 'w');
        }
        SitemapGenerator::create($link)->hasCrawled(function (Url $url) {
            if ($url->segment(1) === 'uploads') {
                return;
            }

            return $url;
        })->writeToFile($path);

        return response()->json('success');
    }
```

Hope this will work for you.